# Excel VBA: paste only value to address from inputbox without loss old format in destination range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, copy-paste, format

I want copy from a range and paste the value only to an destination range chosen with inputbox. It works mostly but the old format of destination range is lost [3rd and 4th row differ from 1st row in the attached link of picture below].

[image]

What I want is the old format is not lost after paste data from copied range. Is there anything wrong?

I use xlPasteValues and here is the code:

```
Sub Ttdn_kc_154()

Dim targetRange As Range

Sheets("ps").Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
Sheets("httk").Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

ActiveSheet.Range("httk_kcKQKD_filter").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
ActiveSheet.Range("httk_kcKQKD_filter").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>0"
If ActiveSheet.Range("httk_lockc1542ps").Value > 0 Then
Range("httk_kcKQKD_datakc").Copy
Set targetRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please input or select a range", Type:=8)
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   [the 3rd and 4th row in attached picture link][1]

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
```

Comment: Why use `xlPasteValues` if you want to keep the formatting?

Comment: To further @cybernetic.nomad's comment, see [this page on pasting values and formats](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b593e52c-910c-4d24-b738-65878fe8a50d/how-to-copypaste-range-values-and-formats?forum=exceldev).  (Hint: You want to also use `xlPasteFormats`).  And here's the [MSDN Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) on `xlPasteType`.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad : I use x1Pastevalues because I want: to paste only content of copied cells and maintain the formatting of destination cells after pasting copied cell onto destination cells.

And the results of destination cells are not what I want. In the attached picture below, the lost formatting of 4th and 5th rows compare with normal formatting of 1st row
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfFan.png

Sorry, I update more info.

Comment: @BruceWayne: two pasted rows in destination cells (sheet "ps") are over-pasted the old formatting and border. I am not sure why
"targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" 
clear formatting and border too.

https://imgur.com/tocxpfY

Comment: Thank all,
It seems change the order of code making everything work:
    Set targetRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select a destination range:", Type:=8)
    Sheets("httk").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("httk_kcKQKD_filter").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    ActiveSheet.Range("httk_kcKQKD_filter").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>0"
    If ActiveSheet.Range("httk_lockc1542ps").Value > 0 Then
    Range("httk_kcKQKD_datakc").Copy
    Sheets("ps").Select
   targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub